# GCC Compile SSE code: undefined reference to `__mm_prefetch`

Tags: c, gcc, sse

I am trying to use _mm_prefetch() function. from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#:%7E:text=%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0prefetcht2%20m8-,CPUID%20Flags%3A%20SSE,-Description), I thought it was from SSE. 
when I compile it with gcc7.3.1, I do like follows:

```
gcc -std=c11 -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -O3 -fopenmp MyApp.c
```

But it complain that

```
conway.c:(.text+0x1ce): undefined reference to `__mm_prefetch'
conway.c:(.text+0x1df): undefined reference to `__mm_prefetch'
conway.c:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `__mm_prefetch'
```

my question is 
(1)Did I miss some library? I google but can not find which library should be linked. 
(2)Is there some book or anyting else that demenstorates how to use SSE instruction for newbie?

thank you!

Comment: Did you include the necessary libraries? Like `#include <immintrin.h>`

Comment: Add `-Wall -Werror`.

Comment: `_mm_foo` functions have one underscore.  Type names like `__m128i` have two underscores.  (If you're building 32-bit code for Windows, an extra `_` would be part of the asm symbol name for functions, in that case you probably just forgot to `#include <immintrin.h>`.)  But anyway, GCC will tell you when you call an undeclared function.  It's an intrinsic, it will inline to a single instruction.  There's no library definition of it.

Comment: @PeterCordes  Oh! I use wrong function name. As you said, it should be `_mm_prefetch` instead of `__mm_prefetch`.  Can you write an answer to let me adopt? And by the way, where can I learn these knowledge? Thank you!

Comment: @RyanJonZhang Really thanks for your help. But it has the same error when I include <immintrin.h>, I have include <mmintrin.h> and <xmmintrin.h>. It turns out I shouldn't add two  `_` before mm, it should be `_mm_prefetch`

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I didn't catch that. Good job though (you can consider adding it as an answer to your own quesion if you want)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Oh, thank you! That really point out what should I change, really useful. I miss them when they are warning.